# Distribution name and PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to know if the following distribution has a name or a PDF in the literature. I have:
$$ Z = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{X_i^2}\right)^{\alpha}$$
where $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ are independent Gaussian random variables with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks.

Comment: With $\mu_i\ne0$, the RV under the radical is a noncentral chi-squared. With $\sigma_i^2\ne1$, I didn't find a name (nonreduced ?). You can call $Z$ a generalized chi-squared.

Comment: @Aaron Where is there a sum of gaussians here?

Comment: @Did I misread the question. Somehow I missed all the exponents.